# Fatal: destination path 'opencv_contrib' already exists and is not an empty directory

Tags: git, macos, opencv

So I tried to get opencv_contrib using :

> $ git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib

Which gave me the following error :

> fatal: destination path 'opencv_contrib' already exists and is not an empty directory.

I tried to check the directory contents :

> $ ls -a

And this is what I got :

[image: screenshot]

Being new to all this, I really am unable to understand what's wrong and what needs to be done. Mainly I need to know how do I make the required directory empty so I can continue with the installation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if `opencv_contrib` is already a Git repo:

```
cd opencv_contrib
git status
```

If it is, a `git pull` (assuming it's still on `master`) should bring it up-to-date.

If it's not a Git repo, and you're sure you don't need what's in it, just remove the directory and try again:

```
cd ..
rm -rf opencv_contrib/
```

Answer (score 0):

If your download/clone was cut short and you cannot finish it, try:

```
cd opencv_contrib
git add .
```

This helped me with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

get in the directory `cd opencv_contrib` .
then check the branch `git branch` 
it shows `* master`it up to date or do`pull origin master`.