# Heroku: How do I deploy to an existing app

Tags: git, heroku

How can I deploy to an existing Heroku app? I have made changes to my app locally and I now was to update my Heroku app with these changes.

To deploy the app for the first time I followed the commands provided by Heroku:

```
heroku login

cd my-project/
git init
heroku git:remote -a test-090909

git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

But now I want to update my app with the changes I have made locally. So I ran the following command in my app to create the new build files:

```
npm run build
```

Then I tried the following commands to push the updated files to Heroku:

```
$ heroku login

$ heroku git:clone -a test-090909
$ cd test-090909

$ git add .
$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
```

But the git:clone command gives me the following error:

```
fatal: destination path 'test-090909' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Comment: have you already checked [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361138/destination-path-already-exists-and-is-not-an-empty-directory)?

Comment: @DaemonPainter thats helped me understand why this error is happening but it doesn't actually help me fix it

Comment: You are cloning into a directory that is not empty. You must clone into an empty directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, make sure your local repository has the latest changes with the following command, 
git add -A
then, 
git commit -m "latest commit"
then push to heroku with 
git push heroku master

HTH